# IOS simulator auto layout issue

Tags: iphone, autolayout, ios-simulator

```
Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)
IOS 8.0
```

I have a screen with 3 buttons
One at the Center, one above and one below.

The screen looks ok in iphone4 and iPhone 6.
But it looks differentt in iPhone 5.
I am using same constrains for all devices.
I checked this on simulator. I don’t’ know is there any
problem with simulator or am i doing something wrong.
The screen shots are attached.

[image: iphone4][image: iphone6]

[image: iphone5]

Comment: If you are expecting to have buttons with certain height(say 40px) in all iPhone models, you need to put height constraints(40px) on the buttons. At the same time, you need to make sure that you are not putting conflicted constraints.

Comment: Height constrain was there.I mentioned same works in iphone4 and iphone6. It shows different in iphone5 simulator

Comment: which constraint applied on button ?